# How to check if an element is focused using bUnit?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, blazor, xunit, bunit

Suppose I have a Blazor component `<MyButton/>` that is implemented like this for simplicity:

```
<button>MyButton</button>
```

And I unit test my component with [bUnit](https://bunit.dev/) as follows:

```
@inherits TestContext

@code {
    [Fact]
    public void MyButton_Focuses_Correctly()
    {
        IRenderedFragment cut = Render(@<MyButton></MyButton>);
        IElement button = cut.Find("button");

        button.Click();

        Assert.True(button.IsFocused); // <- does not work for some reason
    }
}
```

With similar things such as `IsDisabled` or `IsChecked` I could take a look at the DOM attribute but I can't use that workaround with `IsFocused` because there is no such thing as a HTML-`focused` attribute.

```
Assert.True(button.HasAttribute("disabled"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply speaking, bUnit is not a browser and therefore doesn't do "browser-things". What do I mean by that. Clicking on a button will set the focus - but that has nothing to do with your logic, Blazor or ASP.NET Core in general. The behavior is driven by your browser. That is why you can't observe that.

Furthermore, `Click` will not really click your button. The only thing it does, is to invoke your `onclick` event handler. A real "click" from a user in a browser would dispatch numerous events.

If your only concern is that the button has focus after your user clicks the button, then you don't have to test this behavior anyway, as this is 3rd party code (the browser). Especially with unit tests, the rule of thumb is not to test 3rd party behavior.

EDIT: As discussed in the comments - bUnit leverages **AngleSharp** under the hood as the DOM representation. So things like `IsFocused` come from said library. **AngleSharp** has way more use cases than bUnit has - but bUnit can not opt out of certain properties.

Comment: Then why does that property `IsFocused` even exist in the bUnit library?

Comment: This is not from bUnit, but from `Anglesharp` which bUnit uses under the hood.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could maybe include that in your answer as well for any further readers. Going to accept. Just for clarification: Obviously, I'm not interested in whether the browser itself works as expected but instead in whether something happens when my element is focused (by click, tab key, etc.). Perhaps this is an XY problem and I should follow a completely different approach but then I really don't understand why that property is available in bUnit.

Comment: > whether something happens when my element is focused (by click, tab key, etc.).
I do understand that - but it makes sense to distinguish between what is your code and what is 3rd party code. If one uses bUnit, we are talking in the context of unit testing, so we try to isolate the component from external factors (like a browser itself). Also if you would "click" on an a href element in bunit, nothing will happen (well except if you have an onclick eventhandler).

Answer (score -1):

you can call a js method on the button click and set a hidden field or element on the component that **document.activeElement** is current button or not.

```
await JS.InvokeAsync<boo>("hasFocus", button);
```

where hasFocus is just

```
function hasFocus(button) {
  document.getElementById("isButtonFocus").value = (button === document.activeElement);
}
```

In your bunit test you can find and check the value of hidden field

```
// write code to find and check the value of hidden field
cut.Find("#isButtonFocus").value;
```

Comment: In the context of bUnit, that doesn't work. You would have to mock the JavaScript.